# Compute conditionally across rows in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with three relevant columns: id, timepoint and metric (actual size is much larger).

I am trying to calculate the percent change between the metric values at timepoints A and D and use it to create a label (Good metric, Half-decent metric, Subpar metric).

The situation becomes more complicated because if the metric is less than or equal to 2, then the new column should report "Super metric!". If not, then the percent difference should be calculated. Based off of the percent change, the id's will be reported as either "Subpar metric" (< 30%), "Half-decent metric"(30 - 50%), "Good metric" (>50%).
If there is an NA value at timepoints A or D, then returning NA is okay. If timepoint A or D are missing, also return NA.

My initial thought was that I could calculate this in data.table without creating unnecessary columns, but I haven't even been able to get the more simple solution where I do the calculations separately and then join them later.

```
# Example data

library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,6,6,10,10,10,11,11,12,12,14,14),
                  timepoint = c("A","B","C","D","A","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","A","D","A","B","D", "A","D","A","D", "A","D"),
                  metric = c(NA, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, NA, NA, 4, 1, 5, 2, 5,3, 5,5,6,3))
```

Partial solution: first identify the "Super metric" id's, but I would like this to class all instances of "Super metric" id's as such (right now it returns "Super metric" only for timepoint D.

```
# Inefficient solution
# Step 1: Identify id's that need to be computed

dat1 <- dat[, `:=` (Metric_score = if (metric <= 2 & timepoint == "D")
            Metric_score = "Super metric"
            else Metric_score = "Calc PC"),
            by = 'id,timepoint']


# id timepoint metric Metric_score
# 1:  1         A     NA      Calc PC
# 2:  1         B      3      Calc PC
# 3:  1         C      3      Calc PC
# 4:  1         D      4      Calc PC
# 5:  2         A      4      Calc PC # Should be Super metric
# 6:  2         D      2 Super metric
```

Performing the calculation:
This calculates the percent change for all ID's, regardless of whether or not it needs to be calculated

```
# Step 2: Calculate percent change between timepoint D and A

dat[ , `:=`(col = (metric[timepoint == "A"] - metric[timepoint == "D"])/metric[timepoint == "A"]*100), by = 'id']
```

Desired output: Class each metric as "Super metric" when final score (timepoint D) is <= 2, otherwise, calculate percent change ((metric@timeD-metric@timeA)/metric@timeA)*100) and classify based on result ("Subpar metric" (< 30%), "Half-decent metric"(30 - 50%), "Good metric" (>50%)

| id | timepoint | metric | metric_class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | NA | NA |
| 1 | B | 3 | NA |
| 1 | C | 3 | NA |
| 1 | D | 4 | NA |
| 2 | A | 4 | Super metric |
| 2 | D | 2 | Super metric |
| 3 | A | 3 | Super metric |
| 3 | B | 3 | Super metric |
| 3 | C | 2 | Super metric |
| 3 | D | 1 | Super metric |
| 4 | A | 4 | NA |
| 4 | B | 3 | NA |
| 4 | C | NA | NA |
| 6 | A | NA | NA |
| 6 | D | 4 | NA |
| 10 | A | 1 | Super metric |
| 10 | B | 5 | Super metric |
| 10 | D | 2 | Super metric |
| 11 | A | 5 | Half-decent metric |
| 11 | D | 3 | Half-decent metric |
| 12 | A | 5 | Subpar metric |
| 12 | D | 5 | Subpar metric |
| 14 | A | 6 | Good metric |
| 14 | D | 3 | Good metric |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `fcase` should give you a desirable result.

Since 0.5 is both between 0.3-0.5 and >= 0.5 it will take the first case in the list which is "Good metric" in this case, if you want that changed you can simply change the order.

```
metrics <- dcast.data.table(dat, id~timepoint)
metrics[, metric_class := fcase(D <= 2, "Super metric",
                                abs(D-A)/A < 0.3, "Subpar metric",
                                abs(D-A)/A >= 0.5, "Good metric",
                                between(abs(D-A)/A, 0.3, 0.5), "Half-decent metric")]

dat <- merge(dat, metrics[, .(id, metric_class)], by = "id")
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me: I get the following error: ```Error in D <= 2 : 
  comparison (4) is possible only for atomic and list types```. If I change, e.g. ```abs(D-A)/A < 0.3, "Subpar metric"``` to ```abs((metric[timepoint == "D"]-metric[timepoint == "A"])/metric[timepoint == "A"]) < 0.3, "Subpar metric",``` then I get ```Argument #3 has a different length than argument #1. Please make sure all logical conditions have the same length.```

Comment: Did you include the first line (dcast.data.table) in your code?

Comment: That was indeed the problem, but now in trying to implement this on the real data, I had to use ```fun.agg = paste, fill = NA``` to get dcast to work, and this coerces the column classes to 'character'. I think it's the fault of the ```fill```call, but adding/removing brackets doesn't work. I have to force the column class by ```dt$A<- as.numeric(dt$A)``` and then it will run

Comment: Hmmm, do you have ids that have 2 or more of the same timepoint? Otherwise I don't see why R would ask you to use an aggregate function. Can you find a subset of the data where dcast is giving issues and add it to your question? That way it's clear what the problem is

Comment: See below for approach without dcast; however, I would prefer the solution by @WietsedeVries

Comment: @WietsedeVries there were some NA's in my ID column causing me some issues, I got it all sorted. Thanks for your help and the introduction into dcast. I really like how readable the end result is.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that doesn't require `dcast`.

```
metric_class <- function(t,m) {
  if("D" %in% t && m[t=="D"]<=2) return(rep("Super metric", length(t)))
  mvals = c("a"= m[t=="A"], "d" = m[t=="D"])
  val = abs((mvals["d"]-mvals["a"])/mvals["a"])
  return(rep(fcase(val<0.3, "Subpar metric", val>=0.5, "Good metric", val>=0.3 & val<0.5, "Half-decent metric"), length(t)))
}

setDT(dat)[, metric_class:=metric_class(timepoint, metric), by=id][]
```